# API State about sensors [Ubuntu Phone]

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, sensors

Good morning,

I'm wondering if the LightSensor was implemented in the ubuntu-sdk 15.04 ? Because I tried to display the value of the light sensor with a QML app and the SDK 14.04, but it dosn't work (the AmbientLightSensor return a value of 3 and never change - The LightSensor return nothing ) [Sensor SDK](https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/apps/qml/sdk-14.10/QtSensors.AmbientLightSensor/). My BQ Aquaris is under 14.10 version and if the sensor API is implemented in QML with 15.04, I will flash it.

Or maybe you just have another solution to use the LightSensor (QML or not) ?

Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the source code of the current implementation of the automatic screen brightness adjustment.

I think that it is in the powerd daemon:

https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/powerd

And it uses UASensorsLight class from the platform-api:

https://code.launchpad.net/platform-api

But the preferred way is the QML. Maybe I'll test it.